# Can anyone make sense of the below code - basically looking at a vector and counting the number of groups of positive numbers

Tags: r

Can anyone please explain the below code step by step as finding it really hard to understand.

```
pos_z = (graduation$zx1 > 0) * 1 
groups1 =
sum(
     duplicated(c(which(pos_z == 1) - 1, which(pos_z == 0))) * 1)
+ pos_z[1] * 1 



groups1
```

For reference this is graduation$zx1:

```
graduation$zx1
 [1] -0.45324861 -0.73047139  0.43014271 -0.15650837  0.55170381  0.28116438 -0.55591793  0.27227027  0.63245241
[10]  1.46038692 -1.65638629  1.00216479  1.95459264 -1.68571536 -1.13270287 -3.11988512  0.29101822  0.90867925
[19]  0.68966499  0.51921095  0.38606456 -0.12310641  1.93528990 -0.31526050  0.13844854 -0.78646052 -1.36435197
[28]  0.06116645  0.18691062 -0.57250673 -0.39361907  3.20353213 -0.85631237 -1.07256709  0.67213619 -0.92712560
[37] -0.22326398  0.10690621  0.33964185  0.91919458 -0.60972973
```

Tried going through step by step but construction of the group1 variable I'm finding difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks how many consecutive groups of `1`s exist by overlapping (frame shifted) ones and zeros.

Constructing the condition

`pos_z <- (graduation$zx1 > 0) * 1`

generates a boolean `TRUE/FALSE` vector, cast to binary `0` and `1`

- `which(pos_z == 1) - 1`
- `which(pos_z == 0)`

The first `which` gets the positions of ones, minus 1 to overlap the bounds with the neighboring zeros, identified by the second `which`.

- `duplicated(... * 1)`

`duplicated` gets the overlaps (`* 1` just casts the boolean output to `0` and `1`), which are summarized.

The final `pos_z[1] * 1` adds one to the `sum` in case the first value is `1` because that can't be checked by overlapping. `* 1` seems redundant here because `pos_z` is already binary `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

It is finding the number of runs of positive numbers by finding the number of times a non-positive number is immediately followed by a positive number and if the first position is positive that counts as well.

### Code in question

It converts the positive numbers to 1 and the others to 0 giving `pos_z` and then strings out the indexes before the 1's (`wx1` below) followed by the indexes of the 0's (`wx2` below).  For example, let `p6` be the first 6 elements of `pos_z` for ease of exposition.

```
p6 <- pos_z[1:6]; p6
## [1] 0 0 1 0 1 1

wx1 <- which(p6 == 1) - 1; wx1  # positions before the 1's
## [1] 2 4 5

wx2 <- which(p6 == 0); wx2  # positions of the 0's
## [1] 1 2 4

# string out wx1 followed by wx2 and find dups.
# Each dup corresponds to a 0 followed immediately by a 1.
d <- duplicated(c(wx1, wx2)); d
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

# summing has effect of converting TRUE/FALSE to 1/0; then sum.
# Second term adds 1 if the first element of p6 is 1.
sum(d) + p6[1]
## [1] 2
```

In the code in the question there are a number of occurrences of `*1` which converts logical to numeric; however, the only one actually needed is the one in the definition of `pos_z` since the others are multiplying values that are already numeric or are used in a numeric context which will result in automatic conversion.  (`+x` would also convert logical `x` to numeric converting TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.)

### Alternatives

Here are a few other ways to accomplish the same thing:

```
# 1 - rle computes runs so pick out the runs of 1's
sum(rle(pos_z)$values == 1)
## [1] 11

# 2 - pos_z only has 0 and 1 so a diff of 1 must be 0 followed by 1
sum(diff(c(0, pos_z)) == 1)
## [1] 11

# 3
sum(head(c(0, pos_z), -1)  == 0 & pos_z == 1)
## [1] 11

# 4 - run a rolling window of 2 over input and compare each to c(0, 1)
library(zoo)
sum(rollapply(c(0, pos_z), 2, identical, c(0, 1)))
## [1] 11

# 5 - use intersect instead of duplicated
length(intersect(which(pos_z == 1) - 1, which(pos_z == 0))) + pos_z[1]
## [1] 11

# 6 - loop through elements of pos_z
res <- prev <- 0
for(p in pos_z) {
  if (prev == 0 && p == 1) res <- res + 1
  prev <- p
}
res
## [1] 11
```

and here are some that work by converting to strings of 0 and 1:

```
# 7 - replace runs of 1s with single 1, rm 0's and find num chars
nchar(gsub(0, "", gsub("1+", 1, paste(pos_z, collapse = ""))))
## [1] 11

# 8 - paste the 0/1's into a string and search it for "01"
# gregexpr returns -1 if no matches so take max of that and 0
max(sum(sign(unlist(gregexpr("01", paste0(c(0, pos_z), collapse = ""))))), 0)
## [1] 11
```

### Note

```
pos_z <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
```

### Update

Expanded and rearranged alternatives in increasing order of code length.